# update statement in data step

Tags: sas, datastep

In the database we have email address dataset as following. Please notice that there are two observations for id 1003

```
data Email;
    input id$ email $20.;
    datalines;
1001 1001@gmail.com
1002 1002@gmail.com
1003 1003@gmail.com
1003 2003@gmail.com
;
run;
```

And we receive user request to change the email address as following,

```
data amendEmail;
    input id$ email $20.;
    datalines;
1003 1003@yahoo.com
;
run;
```

I attempt to using the `update` statement in the data step

```
data newEmail;
    update Email amendEmail;
    by id;
run;
```

While it only change the first observation for id 1003.

My desired output would be
1001 1001@gmail.com
1002 1002@gmail.com
1003 1003@yahoo.com
1003 1003@yahoo.com

is it possible using non proc sql method?

Comment: Sorry, what is your question exactly? Do you want to change both rows? (in which case you'll just end up with a duplicated row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change both rows, you will end up with duplicates. You should probably address the issue of duplicates in your source table to begin with.

If you need a working solution with duplicated results, consider using PROC SQL with LEFT JOIN and conditional clause for email address.

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE EGTASK.QUERY_FOR_EMAIL AS 
        SELECT t1.id, 
           /* email */
            (CASE WHEN t1.id = t2.id THEN t2.email 
            ELSE t1.email 
            END) AS email 
        FROM WORK.EMAIL t1 
        LEFT JOIN WORK.AMENDEMAIL t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id);
QUIT;
```

As per comments, if you prefer to use data step, you can use the following:

```
data want (drop=email2);
  merge Email amendEmail (rename=(email=email2));
  by id;
  if email2 ne "" then email=email2; 
run;
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer! I am wondering whether there is non-proc sql data step can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Vasilij's merge-based data-step answer will give you the dataset you want, but not in the most efficient way, as it will overwrite the whole `email` dataset, rather than updating just the rows you want to change.

You can use a `modify` statement to change the email address for just the rows from `email` with matching ids in the `amendEmail` dataset.

First, you need to make sure you have an index on `id` in the `email` dataset. This is just a one-off task - as long as you don't overwrite the `email` dataset (e.g. with another data step that doesn't use a `modify` statement, or by sorting it) the index will still be there.

```
proc datasets lib = work nolist;
    modify email;
    index create id;
    run;
quit;
```

Now you can do updates using the index:

```
data email;
    set amendEmail(rename = (email = new_email));
    do until(eof);
        modify email key = id end = eof;
        if _IORC_ then _ERROR_ = 0;
        else do;
            email = new_email;
            replace;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

You should see some output in the log that looks like this, indicating that your dataset has been updated rather than overwritten:

```
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.AMENDEMAIL.
NOTE: The data set WORK.EMAIL has been updated.  There were 2 observations rewritten, 0 observations added and 0 observations 
       deleted.
```

N.B. before you use a `modify` statement like this, make sure that your master `email` dataset is backed up. If the data step is interrupted, it may become corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have unique values in the by variable. In case of duplicates it just updates the first observation. Please refer the link below
  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001329152.htm